# Search for products with their corresponding categories symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to do a query to find me all my products catalog and then list them in my view in this way :

```
    category:
             product
             product
             product
             .......

    category:
             product
             product
             porduct
             .......
etc
```

I do this consultation, but then , as I have no way of showing them in that order , as the consultation brings me only products , and I want to sort them by category .

```
public function findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p, c FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
            JOIN p.category c
            WHERE p.id = :id'
        )->setParameter('id', $id);

    try {
        return $query->getSingleResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

how can I do it??
I thought something like a consultation to bring me the product group them by category and then make a cut control.
But not how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method's name is `findOneByIdJoinedToCategory` which means to me that you are going to select only one product, so why do you need to sort them if it's only one product? Or, you should to rename this method.

If you are trying to select all products grouped or ordered by category you can reverse your DQL to select Categories and sort them, then you can get products of every category with the getter:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT c FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Category c ORDER BY c.name ASC'
    );
```

Then for every category you can get their products with:

```
$category->getProducts();
```

If this solution isn't responding to your needs you can continue with your approach but you need to change your DQL to:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN p.category c ORDER BY c.name ASC');
```

or if you want to use a group by clause it would look like this:

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Product p JOIN p.category c GROUP BY c.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$result = $em
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c.name AS category, p.name AS product')
    ->from('AppBundle:Product', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Category', 'c', Join::WITH, 'p.category = c.id')
    ->orderBy('category', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('product', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult()
;
```

as result you'll receive something like:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'category' => 'c1',
    'product' => 'p1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'category' => 'c2',
    'product' => 'p2',
  ),
  // ...
)
```

hope it's exactly your desire.